# How to realise a dynamic AND combined query on a ManyToMany relation in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two simple models. Let's say Tags and Posts. They look like this (simplified):

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, default='')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

So, each tags can be assigned to n posts and vice versa.

I'm trying to get a list of either all posts where ANY of the given tags are assigned, or where ALL of the given tags are assigned.

So basically I want an OR or an AND combination.

The OR is easy enough. In my view I do (assume "tags" is a list of Tag objects)

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(tags__in=tags)
```

But I can't figure out how to do that for an AND combination. I either get nothing or the same as with OR. I tried a lot of different things, but nothing worked in my scenario, where I have a dynamic list of tags to filter by.

My most promising approach looked like this:

```
filter = [Q(tags=tag) for tag in tags if tag.enabled == True]
qs = Post.objects.all()
qs = qs.filter(reduce(operator.__and__, filter))
```

This still returns an empty list. And yes I am 100% sure that I have Post records, with both requested tags assigned to it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the answer is, as usual, relativly simple:

```
qs = Post.objects.all()
for tag in tags:
    qs = qs.filter(tags=tag)
```

Comment: Your approach totally works but keeping a production environment with 100 thousands of entries in mind, it might make sense to limit your search space to those entries which have the exact amount of tags you are looking for (see my answer below)

Comment: Well, that is not the behaviour I want to achieve. Since a Post could have n Tags only checking for Posts with the exact number of requested tags would not give me the expected result.
Performance is not an issue in my case. It's a private project and I don't expect huge amounts of data anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve your desired filter, we can do something like this:

```
wanted_tags = [tag_1, tag_2, tag_3,...]

# To keep it as lean as possible, we first minimise our search space by filtering solely the posts with the amount of tags in the first place:
preprocessed_posts = Post.objects.annotate(c=Count('tags')).filter(c=len(wanted_tags))

# Now comes the somewhat pythonic part, which is simple but feels kinda hacky:
for tag in wanted_tags:
    preprocessed_posts.filter(tags=tag)

# now preprocessed_posts contains the wanted entities
wanted_posts = preprocessed_posts
```